# Regex Match Help? Close after space

Tags: regex

I am looking to create a regex solution to find a code in text.

```
Random information here Here code: FJF402 Random information here
```

The common factors in the text are;

'Here code: '

The result should be 'FJF402'

Any suggestions welcome, much appreciated.

Comment: What regex flavor?  Is "Here code: " a literal string to search for?  What defines the end of the match?  A space?  This pattern works in the latter case in PCRE: `(?<=Here code: ).+?(?= )`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.

To confirm, a space is the end of the match.

Answer (score -1):

Migrating my comment to an answer, you can use:

```
(?<=Here code: ).+?(?= )
```

- `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind, which means the expression will only match if it comes right after the contents of the lookbehind.  In this case, the content of the lookbehind is the literal string "Here code: ".
- `.+?` matches one or of any character, but the `?` means this is a lazy match, so it will match the fewest characters possible to satisfy the expression.
- `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead, which means the expression will only match if it comes right before the contents of the lookahead.  In this case, the content of the lookahead is a literal space.  Since the previous part of the expression was a lazy match, this forces the expression to match all of the characters up to the space.